# Error in Making Oauth 2.0 request from Frontend

Tags: javascript, oauth-2.0, oauth, google-api, google-oauth

I am running my frontend on localhost:3000. It has a buttons that should make a API call to my backend server running on localhost:4000/auth/google for Oauth 2.0 consent and further callbacks
The problem is that I have tested the Oauth controllers and it works fine but when I make request from frontend button I get error:

[image: Error Message in Console]

I though of it as a CORS error but It is not because I checked the network log:

[image: Network Console]

**Code For index.js and backend routes**

```
app.use(session({ secret:process.env.SECRET }));
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());


app.get('/',(req,res)=>
{
    res.send('<a href="/auth/google">Auth With Google</a>')
})

app.get('/auth/google',

    passport.authenticate('google')

)

app.get('/auth/google/callback',
    passport.authenticate('google',
    {
        successRedirect:'http://localhost:3000/',
        failureRedirect:'/failure'
    })
)
```

**Passport GoogleStrategy**

```
passport.use(new GoogleStrategy({
    clientID:     GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID,
    clientSecret: GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET,
    callbackURL: "http://localhost:4000/auth/google/callback",
    scope: [
        'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube', // Required to access YouTube data
        'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile', // Optional: access to user's profile
      ],
    passReqToCallback   : true
  },
  async function(request, accessToken, refreshToken, profile, done) {
    const response = await user.create({ googleId: profile.id, 
                                                accessToken:accessToken }); 
    return done(null,response);
  }
));
```

**Frontend React Code**

```
function App() {
  // Function to start the OAuth 2.0 authorization process
  const handleAuthClick = async () => {
    // Send a request to your Express.js backend to initiate the OAuth flow
    try {
      const response = fetch('http://localhost:4000/auth/google');
      // const response  = await axios.get("/auth/google"); // Tried Both Ways
      } 
    catch (error) {
      console.error('Error initiating OAuth flow:', error);
    }
  };

  return (
    <div className='App flex flex-col gap-4'>
      <h1>Your App</h1>
      <button onClick={handleAuthClick}>Authorize YouTube Access</button>
    </div>
    
  );
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow  Please read: [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/4800344)